# The image of an 'almost injective' map is a linear graph

Tags: algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space of dimension (Lebesgue covering dimension) $1$. For each  continuous map $f\in \mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb R^3)$ let $$\Delta f=\sup \{\text{diam }f^{-1}(\{z\}) : z\in X \}.$$
And define for each $\varepsilon>0$ the set $U_\varepsilon$ to be the collection of all $f\in \mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb R^3)$ such that $\Delta f<\epsilon$. It is easy to see that the sets $U_\varepsilon$ are open. To see that they are open we fix some $f\in \mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $\delta>0$. We construct a continuous map $g\in U_\varepsilon$ such that $$\rho(f,g)=\sup\{\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert:x\in X\}<\delta.$$
For this purpose let $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ be a finite cover of $X$ of order at most $m+1$ such that $\text{diam} U_i<\varepsilon/2$ and  $\text{diam} f(U_i)<\delta/2$. Let $\{\phi_i\}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to this cover, and let $\{z_i\}$ be a set of points in $\mathbb R^3$ in general position such that $z_i$ is within $\delta/2$ of $f(x_i)$, where each $x_i$ is a fixed point of $U_i$. Finally we let $$g(x)=\sum_i\phi_i(x)z_i;$$ it is not difficult to see that $g$ is the desired map. This show that $U_\varepsilon$ is dense. I would want to show that $g$ actually maps $X$ onto a (finite) linear graph in $\mathbb R^3$. I guess that the vertices of such graph would be $z_i$. Thus I would need to show that if $x_i$ and $x_j$ lie in the same (path?) component, then there is a connected subset $U_{ij}$ of $X$ homeomorphic to a closed interval. But I am unsure of how to proceed.